# How to perform particle swarm optimization clustering of results obtained from tf-idf vectorizer?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clustering, python

I have a collection of news articles. I have performed tf-idf operations on them. I am using python as programming language so it was just the use of TF-IDF vectorizer function. I now have the document's tfidf representation. My aim is to cluster news articles using Particle swarm optimization.

As read in following research papers,

1. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4170865_Document_clustering_using_particle_swarm_optimization
2. https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0188815
3. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877750316305002

the input of the PSO algorithm should be an array representing document. In my case I am trying to use tf-idf as input. So, how can i use the result of tf-idf as input for Particle Swarm optimization? Particle Swarm optimization is a optimization algorithm. So while clustering, I am going to optimize or minimize distance between cluster's centroid and data points belonging to that cluster. Can anybody provide me a solution or hint towards something?

Comment: [Particle swarm optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) is used for "**optimizes** a problem by iteratively trying to improve a candidate solution with regard to a given measure of quality". Can you edit the question to add a reference where PSO is used for clustering?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91318/discussion-between-annonymous-programmer-and-d-w).

Comment: You mention you've read some research papers where this is done.  As Apass.Jack suggested earlier, I suggest you edit the question to provide references to the papers  you read that do this, and summarize what you do understand about them and what you don't understand.  I still suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  I suspect what you really want to do is cluster the documents, and there are many reasonable methods for clustering; it's not clear why you are so focused on PSO-based clustering as opposed to any other method for clustering.